# fastest way to access the least significant bit of an integer?

Tags: c, assembly

I was reading a book about assembly, and here it comes a statement that i don't quite understand. It says the most efficient way to access the least significant bit is by using the following code:

```
*(unsigned char*)&a
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is fast?

I was told that i need to understand assembly well to get this.

Comment: Either you've misread the book, or it was incorrect. This accesses the *least* significant *byte* for little-endian, but *most* significant *byte* for big-endian. For middle-endian, it accesses who-knows-what.

Comment: and the code should be `*(unsigned char*)&a` give `a` is `int` and not a pointer.

Comment: `int x = 23456;  int y = x & 0x0001;` ...  `y` holds LSB of `x`

Comment: Yes, as @ryyker said for LSB. Or just `x & 1` for short. This *is* portable (assuming `x` is an integral type), regardless of endianness.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you that makes a lot more sense now. but could you pls elaborate why this code can be used to access the least significant bit?

Comment: Can you disclose the assembly target? What you have read is true for some processors, may be true for others, and a complete lie for the rest. For example, on many architectures reading `int` would be faster than `byte`.

Comment: _I was told that i need to understand assembly well to get this_.  ***Do you?***  (i.e., if you do not, as you say, an explanation in assembly would do no good)

Comment: @Jackddddd: If you're talking about the code in your question, then I can answer that: It can't (see my comment above; note my use of "byte", not "bit" in the comment). If you mean my `x & 1` case, then it's doing a bitwise `AND` with the value `1` (which has *only* the LSB set).

Comment: No need to understand assembly here. Basic memory and pointers understanding will do (given we are talking of bytes, not bits, as the title says).

Comment: Btw, any1 knows modern processor that can read byte faster than int? Not talking about cache lines...

Comment: ***[this may be useful to you](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)*** (look at the very first link)

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk: If you count microcontrollers as modern processors (and they are! --- not quite as powerful as your desktop CPU perhaps, but many sure as hell are modern), then just about any recent 8-bit model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain.

Whenever you variable are stored in memory, it has several important properties:

- Address
- Size
- Type

From your question, I suspect you are asking about integer variable of size greater, than 1. For example, `int` type is defined by C standard as something `fast` and `at least 16 bit`. Which makes it 2 to 4 bytes.

So, lets take `int` has a size of 4.

Then we know, the variable occupies four bytes with some starting address (`&a`): addr+0, addr+1, addr+2, addr+3.

When talking about C conventions, you can convert pointer from one type into another, and use it for accessing the data (assuming you know what you are doing). In our case we know, that `char` is just 1 byte long. So we can extract 4 `char`s from a single `int` by using direct memory access:

```
char ch0 = *((char *)&a + 0); // OR ((char*)&a)[0]
char ch1 = *((char *)&a + 1); // OR ((char*)&a)[1]
char ch2 = *((char *)&a + 2); // OR ((char*)&a)[2]
char ch3 = *((char *)&a + 3); // OR ((char*)&a)[3]
```

Now we have 4 bytes, and the question is: which one contains which values. Ie, when our `a` equals to `0x12345678`, we may have multiple alternative approaches, how different parts are ordered in memory.

On x86 (which is close enough to your case), the order is such, so the lowest part of our `int` (0x78) is stored first, then the second one and so on:

```
a              : 0x12345678
((char*)&a)[0] : 0x78
((char*)&a)[1] : 0x56
((char*)&a)[2] : 0x34
((char*)&a)[3] : 0x12
```

So, to access lest significant bit, we need to access least significant bit from the least significant byte. And, the winner is `*(char*)&a`. But the bit value is:

```
*(char*)&a & 1
```

Now, about why it is not quite true. Even on x86. Unlike we talk about true 8-bit processors, the design of many processors is optimized to access aligned data in a way that is fastest when it matches register size. So if processor has 32-bit registers, it is likely to read 4 bytes faster than 1, because reading one actually means 2 operations: read 4, truncate & expand sign.

Comment: There is also second layer of ambiguity. An [optimizing compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) may replace `*(char*)&a & 1` construct with whatever it thinks to be faster or leave it alone as is. Yet, it's hard to predict final performance without looking into generated assembly and confront it with parameters like instruction latencies for given CPU.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski it may. if type and usage scope permits. i.e. variable is not volatile, and there are no other non-restricted pointers. but the question has been about why accessing first byte might give desired result...

Comment: Sure, I was referring to the "fastest way" part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you made an error in transcribing/paraphrasing what the book says.

First of all,

```
*(unsigned char*)&a
```

doesn't access a bit. It accesses a byte.

Second, it is *not necessarily* the least signification byte. It is the least significant byte on a little endian system. On a big endian system, it is the most significant byte.

In either case, it is accessing the lowest addressed byte of the integer.

Comment: Maybe it should be noted, that in either case it is accessing the lowest addressed byte composing the integer.